# Using "discriminator" keyword in JSON schema

Tags: json, jsonschema, discriminator

I'm trying to have kind of polymorphic behavior in JSON. I have the following example JSON which I want to validate against the JSON schema below:

**simplified_example.json**

```
{
    "header": null,

    "body": null,

    "footer": {
        "kpis": {
            "metrics_name": "metrics_type_2",
            "metrics_value": 3.141592
        }
    }
}
```

**simplified_schema.schema.json**

```
{
  "definitions": {
    "metrics_name_output_type": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": [
        "metrics_type_1",
        "metrics_type_2",
        "metrics_type_3"
      ]
    }
  },

  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "title": "The Root Schema",
  "required": [
    "header",
    "body",
    "footer"
  ],

  "properties": {

    "header": {
      "$id": "#/properties/header",
      "type": "null"
    },

    "body": {
      "$id": "#/properties/body",
      "type": "null"
    },

    "footer": {
      "$id": "#/properties/footer",
      "type": "object",
      "title": "The Footer Schema",

      "kpis": {
        "title": "The Kpis Schema",
        "$id": "#/properties/footer/properties/kpis",
        "discriminator": {
          "tag": "metrics_name",
          "mapping": {
            "metrics_type_1": {
              "properties": {
                "metrics_value": { "type": "string" }
              }
            },
            "metrics_type_2": {
              "properties": {
                "metrics_value": { "type": "number" }
              }
            },
            "metrics_type_3": {
              "properties": {
                "metrics_value": { "type": "integer" }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that I don't understand how to apply the "discriminator" I've written.
My example JSON against my example schema seems always VALID according to a bunch of validators. E.g this one:

https://jsonschemalint.com/#!/version/draft-07/markup/json

What Should I edit/put in addition to restrict **"string"** in case of **"metrics_type_3"** selection for example (correct would be **"integer"**)?

Comment: Hey! `discriminator` is actually not JSON Schema, and is in fact an additon created by OpenAPI specification. This fact might explain why normal JSON Schema libraries don't work with normal JSON Schema libraries. The schema is still considered valid because, unknown keywords are ignored.

Comment: It is described "discriminator" keyword here:
https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-json-schema-language-00#section-5.3.7

Comment: I'm afraid that is not JSON Schema. -_- Someone published a very similar sounding specification, but it got renamed to "JSON Data Definition Format" (see https://github.com/json-schema-language links to new github org)